# Update MySQL table rows where and set clause same values of the column

Tags: mysql

I would like to update an MySQL Table for a few rows.

```
update pages
set icon = Arrow
where icon = ArrowBottom;
```

This didn't work it keeps telling me unknown column ArrowBottom.

Comment: Put the string in single quotes otherwise it will be treated as a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution for my question:

```
update pages
set icon = 'Arrow'
where icon = 'ArrowBottom';
```